# How do I register my custom UDF so I can run it in spark-shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I defined the following custom UDF:

```
def stddev1 (columnName: Column): Column = {
    sqrt(avg(columnName * columnName) - avg(columnName) * avg(columnName))
}
```

I want to run this function in spark-shell and test it with some example data but I keep running into errors: "Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.Column is not supported."

I might have to register it but I'm unsure how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you want to use it. For example, this works fine:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(1,2,3,4)).toDF("myCol")
df.show

>+-----+
>|myCol|
>+-----+
>|    1|
>|    2|
>|    3|
>|    4|
>+-----+

def stddev(col: Column): Column = sqrt(avg(col * col) - avg(col) * avg(col))
df.agg(stddev($"myCol")).first

> [1.118033988749895]
```

However if you want to use it within a Spark SQL statement, you will need something like this:

```
val squared = (s: Int) => {
  s * s
}
sqlContext.udf.register("square", squared)

%sql select id, square(id) as id_squared from test
```

Check [this](https://docs.cloud.databricks.com/docs/latest/databricks_guide/06%20Spark%20SQL%20%26%20DataFrames/03%20UDF%20and%20UDAF%20-%20scala.html) out for more info.